# how to combine duplicate key in dictionary and sum up values in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter, swift3

```
var dictionary: [String : Any] = [:]
              
for revenueItem in revenues {                        
    if let currentValue = dictionary[revenueItem.customerName] {                    
        dictionary[revenueItem.customerName] = [currentValue] + [revenueItem.revenue]
        print("hellooooooooooo \(currentValue)")
    } else {
        dictionary[revenueItem.customerName] = [revenueItem.revenue]
    }
}
```

like i have a 2 customer name with the same keys but different values. i want to sum up their values and make only one key in output but have a total value.
In my tableview cell appears duplicated and not sum up the values and the customername (key) is also duplicated. please help.. i tried everything but failed to correct the output.

Comment: Why are you using a `[String: Any]`? Show us your table view code. That probably needs changing as you seem to be using the wrong type here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary.init<S>(_ keysAndValues: S, uniquingKeysWith combine: (Value, Value) throws -> Value)`, which takes a `Sequence` of tuples, storing the key-value pairs and a closure, which defines how to handle duplicate keys.

```
// Create the key-value pairs
let keysAndValues = revenues.map { ($0.customerName, $0.revenue) }
// Create the dictionary, by adding the values for matching keys
let revenueDict = Dictionary(keysAndValues, uniquingKeysWith: { $0 + $1 })
```

Test code:

```
struct RevenueItem {
    let customerName: String
    let revenue: Int
}

let revenues = [
    RevenueItem(customerName: "a", revenue: 1),
    RevenueItem(customerName: "a", revenue: 9),
    RevenueItem(customerName: "b", revenue: 1)
]

let keysAndValues = revenues.map { ($0.customerName, $0.revenue) }
let revenueDict = Dictionary(keysAndValues, uniquingKeysWith: { $0 + $1 })
revenueDict // ["a": 10, "b": 1]
```

Comment: how to make it a for loop?
my data is coming from the database. 
these are the dictionary. how to make it the total value of KFC and make it as a one key as an ouput.?

"customerName": "KFC"
"revenue": 12345.2
"salesType": "Revenue"

"customerName": "KFC"
"revenue": 12345.2
"salesType": "Revenue"

"customerName": "Andoks"
"revenue": 54321.4
"salesType": "Revenue"

Comment: @miniosdwarf there's no need for a for loop. My code already does exactly what you are looking for. If you gave it a try, you'd see.